# How to reset global variable in python?

Tags: python, django

```
SOME_VARIABLE = []

def some_fun:
    append in SOME_VARIABLE
    s = []
    s = SOME_VARIABLE
    SOME_VARIABLE = []  // Not setting to empty list.
    return s
```

How to reset `SOME_VARIABLE` to empty.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you read a variable, Python looks for it in the entire scope chain. This mean that:

```
GLOB_VAR = "Some string"

def some_fun():
    print GLOB_VAR
```

will print `Some string`

Now, if you write to a variable, Python looks for it in the local scope, and if it cannot find a variable with the name you gave at the local level, then it creates one.

This means that in your example, you have created a variable named `SOME_VARIABLE` local to your `some_fun` function, instead of updating the global `SOME_VARIABLE`. This is a classic python gotcha.

If you want to write to your global, you have to explicitly tell Python that you are talking about a global variable that already exists. To do so, you need to use the `global` keyword. So, the following:

```
GLOB_VAR = "Some string"

def some_fun():
    global GLOB_VAR
    GLOB_VAR = "Some other string"

some_fun()
print GLOB_VAR
```

will print `Some other string`.

Note: *I see it as a way of encouraging people to keep global variables read-only, or at least to think about what they're doing*.

The behaviour is the same (just a bit more surprising) when you try to read first and then write to a global. The following:

```
GLOB_VAR = False

def some_fun():
    if GLOB_VAR:
        GLOB_VAR = False

some_fun()
```

will raise:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "t.py", line 7, in <module>
    some_fun()
  File "t.py", line 4, in some_fun
    if GLOB_VAR:
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'GLOB_VAR' referenced before assignment
```

because since we will modify `GLOB_VAR`, it is considered a local variable.

*Update*: [Ely Bendersky](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8206/eli-bendersky) has a related [in-depth post](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/05/15/understanding-unboundlocalerror-in-python/) about this that is worth a read for more formal details.

Answer (score 9):

You need to tell the interpreter that you are talking about a global variable:

```
def some_fun:
    global SOME_VARIABLE
    ...
    SOME_VARIABLE = []
```

Answer (score 3):

if you don't need the SOME_VARIABLE anymore you could use:

```
del SOME_VARIABLE
```

if you want a empty list:

```
del SOME_VARIABLE[:]
```

Answer (score 0):

`SOME_VARIABLE` is global, so rebinding it won't take effect unless you use `global`. But since it's a mutable object, just mutate it appropriately.

```
del SOME_VARIABLE[:]
```